# Two nvd3 graphs next to each other

Tags: angular, mean-stack, nvd3.js, bootstrap-4

I have two nvd3 graphs that I would like to show next to each other on the page. Here are my current html codes:

```
<div class="container" >

  <!-- Graph 1-->
  <div class="rows">
    <nvd3 [options]="optionsGraph1" [data]="Graph1Data"></nvd3>
  </div>

  <!-- Graph 2 and 3 that should be next to each other -->
  <div class="rows">
      <div class="col-md-6"><nvd3 [options]="optionsGraph2" [data]="Graph2Data"></nvd3></div>
      <div class="col-md-6"><nvd3 [options]="optionsGraph3" [data]="Graph3Data"></nvd3></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Graph2 and Graph3 have a size that would fit in a column however they are still displayed below each other. I am using Angular 2 and bootstrap 4.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I might be wrong but you only defined grid for `Medium devices Desktops (≥992px)` try adding other grids col-sx, col-sm, col-lg

Comment: Not related but your class `rows` should be `row`. Can you show us what does nvd3 generates?

Answer (score 0):

Your nvd3 graph probably has a fixed width, but there's too little information to see what is going wrong without a fiddle. Can you adjust the svg css rule to be width: 100%?

As some other user has noticed, you have named the .row container as .rows, if this is unintended, there's a chance the absence of clearfix that bootstrap .row adds is altering the way columns are floating.